# ¿Como hacer una búsqueda sin distinción de mayúsculas y minúsculas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Si busco por ejemplo la palabra **Pedro**, que la hora de escribir en el buscador lo pueda hacer si pongo todo minúscula **pedro** o mayúsculas **PEDRO** y al final me busque la palabra.

Lo que hace el siguiente código es que tengo que escribir exactamente la palabra como tal **Pedro** para que encuentre la coincidencia y yo quiero lo que ya mencione anteriormente.

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#clie").keyup(function () {
                var busqueda = $("#clie").val();
               
                if(busqueda.length >= 2){ 
                //si la busqueda es menor a cinco no busca nada
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "<?php  echo base_url();  ?>fiscales/get_nombre_cliente",
                            data: {
                                cl_nombre: $("#clie").val()
                            },
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data.length > 0) {
                                    $('#DropdownCliente').empty();
                                    $('#clie').attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                                    $('#DropdownCliente').dropdown('toggle');
                                }
                                else if (data.length == 0) {
                                    $('#clie').attr("data-toggle", "");
                                }
                                $.each(data, function (key,value) {
                                    if (data.length >= 0)
                                        $('#DropdownCliente').append('<li onClick="asignar_cliente('+value.cl_id_cliente+')"  role="presentation" ><a role="menuitem dropdownnameli" class="dropdownlivalue">' + value['cl_nombre'] + "&nbsp;" + value['cl_apellido_paterno'] + '</a></li>');
                                });
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
            $('ul.txtcliente').on('click', 'li a', function () {
                $('#clie').val($(this).text());
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: ¿podrías estilizar tu código?

Comment: Lo que quiero es lo siguiente, si busco por ejemplo la palabra Pedro, que la hora de escribir en el buscador lo pueda hacer si pongo todo miniscula pedro o mayusculas PEDRO y al final me busque la palabra, lo que hace el codigo es que tengo que escribir exactamente la palabra como tal Pedro para que encuentre la coincidencia y yo quiero lo que ya mencione anteriormente

Comment: Listo ya esta con estilo

Comment: Pues yo voy a ir en contra de lo que te ponen en las respuestas: esto no es algo que debas solucionar en jQuery sino del lado del servidor. La cadena que jQuery te manda y que el usuario escribe debería mantenerse tal cual y mover el problema a la base de datos o a PHP (el lenguaje que estás usando)

Comment: deberias tener un atributo extra en tu base de datos con el texto en minusculas y cuando recibas la cadena también la conviertes a minusculas y la comparas con la de la base

Comment: El problema de tener un atributo/columna más en la base de datos, es que debería ser uno para cada columna en la que se pueda hacer búsquedas, lo que puede ser poco conveniente y difícil de mantener si son muchos campos. No sé si sería mejor ajusta la colación de las columnas para que las búsquedas no dependan de la notación usada.

Answer (score 7):

Lo ponía como comentario, pero lo voy a poner como respuesta: creo que estás planteando mal el asunto: esto es un problema que no debería solucionarse desde el lado del cliente, sino desde el lado del servidor.

En JavaScript/jQuery (lado del cliente) no se debería realizar ninguna operación que afecte *de manera crítica* el funcionamiento de PHP/base de datos (lado del servidor). Al menos por 2 motivos:

- Los usuarios pueden cambiar y sobreescribir los valores de JavaScript/jQuery. Es por eso que, por ejemplo, la validación de valores debe hacerse siempre en el servidor (independientemente de que se haga en el cliente).
- Quieres mantener tu estructura y servidor como una caja negra: mientras menos información tenga el usuario, mejor. ¿Por qué? Porque hay gente que no tiene buenas intenciones y mientras menos sepan, más difícil van a tener hacerte la vida difícil a ti.

Sé que en tu caso sería simplemente poner una cadena en minúsculas, que es algo insignificante, pero no deja de ser una información que el usuario no necesita saber.

Teniendo eso en cuenta, dejaría el código JavaScript que tienes tal cual está sin cambios de ningún tipo, porque las operaciones deberías realizarlas en el lado del servidor... Y aquí es donde mi respuesta va a ser genérica porque no tengo información sobre tu servidor (sólo sé que usas PHP, pero no sé si estás usando una base de datos o cuál).

---

**Cambia a minúsculas en PHP**

Como menciona [aldanux en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36478/250), en PHP puedes usar la función [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtolower.php) para transformar una cadena a minúsculas. Esto lo vas a tener que hacer de todos modos porque, como comentaba antes, no puedes fiarte de las entradas de usuario, por lo que si vas a transformar a minúsculas, deberás hacerlo en el lado del servidor.

Esto lo necesitarías tanto si vas a buscar en PHP (en un array u objeto) o si vas a buscar en una base de datos (ver abajo).

---

**Usa colaciones que no diferencien entre mayúsculas y minúsculas**

Si estás usando una base de datos para realizar las búsquedas y estás teniendo problemas con las mayúsculas/minúsculas, eso se puede deber a que estás usando una colación (*collation*) que diferencia entre mayúsculas/minúsculas (*case sensitive*) en la base de datos o en la columna donde realizas la búsqueda.

Entonces una recomendación sería que cambiaras la colación (al menos la de esa columna) a una que no diferencie entre mayúsculas y minúsculas (*case insensitive*). Esas colaciones son fáciles de identificar porque su nombre termina en `_ci`. Así por ejemplo, si estás usando MySQL y tu columna tiene colación `utf8_bin`, podrías cambiarla a `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Aunque esta solución puede no valerte dependiendo de la arquitectura que estés siguiendo.

---

**Transforma a minúsculas en la base de datos**

Si estás usando una base de datos para realizar las búsquedas, podrías utilizar las funciones que transforman a minúsculas de la propia base de datos. Por ejemplo, en MySQL, sería el método [`LOWER()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) o `LCASE()`.

Cambia la cadena de búsqueda directamente en PHP (como se explica en el primer método usando `strtolower`) para sólo tener que realizar la operación de minúsculas en la columna de la base de datos (en lugar de realizar la misma operación por cada fila).

Entonces en tu claúsula WHERE harías algo como esto:

```
SELECT nombre, apellidos, direccion, etc
FROM   usuarios
WHERE  LOWER(nombre) = 'pedro';
```

Esto va a significar que tu base de datos va a hacer más operaciones (aunque no excesivamente costosas) por lo que la búsqueda sería algo más lenta.

Comment: @aldanux ¿por qué? Tú respuesta era válida.